# Managed phone information

Tags: mobile-device-management

When I upgraded my iPhone 6 to 9.3.1, it started to show message "this phone is managed by your organization."  In Settings it states phone managed by Comcast.  This is NOT a company phone.  My personal phone.  I believe it is what keeps me from using international SIM card.  Can't mast says this IMEI is not in their system.  Help! 
Sorry if this question doesn't meet rules.  I am still learning.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a Comcast profile in your iPhone if you use Comcast/Xfinity to access the internet.  You can remove the profile by following these steps:

1. Go to **Settings --> General --> Profiles**.
2. If you see a **Configuration Profile** named *Comcast* or *Xfinity* or something similar, tap it.
3. At the bottom you'll see a button named **Delete Profile**.  Tap, and confirm, to delete.
4. Restart the iPhone

Next time you try to access Comcast again, you'll be prompted to reinstall the profile.  There's nothing wrong with installing and deleting the profile, although it is annoying.  If you use the iPhone thru your company, like with *Good Email*, your company might've installed this profile.